# Scrolling part of the canvas

Tags: canvas, scroll, swt, scrollbar

I wrote the the below code to solve the problem mentioned at [Scrolling canvas content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133999/scrolling-canvas-content).

```
package com.cavium.test.views;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ScrollBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Test2 {
    private static final int CYCLE_OFFSET = 120;
    protected static final int Y_STEP = 20;
    static int shellStyle = SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.RESIZE;
    static int canvasStyle = SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display, shellStyle);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setBackground(display.getSystemColor((SWT.COLOR_CYAN)));
        shell.setText("Canvas Test");
        shell.setSize(400, 300);

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(composite, canvasStyle);
        canvas.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        final Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
        final ScrollBar hBar = canvas.getHorizontalBar();
        hBar.setMaximum(2120);
        hBar.setMinimum(0);
        hBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                switch (event.detail) {
                case SWT.DRAG:
                    System.out.println("drag");
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_DOWN:
                    System.out.println(" arrow down");
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_UP:
                    System.out.println("arrow up");
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_LEFT:
                    System.out.println("arrow left");
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_RIGHT:
                    System.out.println("arrow right");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("In hori");
                int hSelection = hBar.getSelection();
                int destX = -hSelection - origin.x;
                System.out.println("origin.x " + origin.x + "hSelection " + hSelection + " destX " + destX);
                canvas.scroll(140 + destX, 0, 140, 0, 2120, 2000, false);
                origin.x = -hSelection;
                System.out.println("origin.x " + origin.x);
            }

        });
        final ScrollBar vBar = canvas.getVerticalBar();
        vBar.setMaximum(2000);
        vBar.setMinimum(0);
        vBar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                System.out.println("In ver");
                int vSelection = vBar.getSelection();
                int destY = -vSelection - origin.y;
                canvas.scroll(0, destY, 0, 0, 2120, 2000, false);
                origin.y = -vSelection;
            }

        });
        canvas.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                System.out.println("In resize");
                Rectangle client = canvas.getClientArea();
                hBar.setMaximum(2120);
                vBar.setMaximum(2000);
                hBar.setThumb(Math.min(2120, client.width));
                hBar.setPageIncrement(Math.min(2120, client.width));
                vBar.setThumb(Math.min(2000, client.height));
                vBar.setPageIncrement(Math.min(2000, client.height));
                hBar.setIncrement(20);
                vBar.setIncrement(20);
                int hPage = 2120 - client.width;
                int vPage = 2000 - client.height;
                int hSelection = hBar.getSelection();
                int vSelection = vBar.getSelection();
                if (hSelection >= hPage) {
                    if (hPage <= 0)
                        hSelection = 0;
                    origin.x = -hSelection;
                }
                if (vSelection >= vPage) {
                    if (vPage <= 0)
                        vSelection = 0;
                    origin.y = -vSelection;
                }
                System.out.println("hPage " + hPage + " hSelection " + hSelection + " origin.x " + origin.x + " origin.y "
                        + origin.y);
                canvas.redraw();
            }
        });
        // Create a paint handler for the canvas
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                System.out.println("In paint");
                System.out.println(origin.x);
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    e.gc.drawString("Row Header" + i, origin.x, origin.y + i * Y_STEP);
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                        e.gc.drawRectangle(origin.x + CYCLE_OFFSET + j * 20, origin.y + i * Y_STEP, 20, 20);
                        e.gc.drawString(new Integer(j).toString(), origin.x + CYCLE_OFFSET + 2 + j * 20, origin.y + i * Y_STEP
                                + 1);
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();

    }
}
```

But facing the below issues:

1. In horizontal scrollbar listener am not able to detect the events on scrollbar. Nothing is printing here.
2. When I drag the scrollbar thumb or click on the area between thumb and LEFT or RIGHT arrow button  or LEFT ARROW button , the code is not working.

Can anyone point out the bug in this code?
I am not understood how scrolling is happening. Can Somebody please provide me the links, tutorials/screen cast about SWT,Canvas and scrolling.

Comment: Your listeners seem to be working fine, whenever i change horizontal scrolling, I see this text printed: "drag In hori origin.x 0 hSelection 0 destX 0 origin.x 0"

Comment: Which OS are you using? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I am using Windows XP.