# Why does the SWT Selection event for a slider never have a detail?

Tags: java, swt, cross-platform

I was following the SWT Slider Snippet example and the event detail is always 0 aka SWT.NONE on fedora yet the detail is set on windows 7. The example can be found here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTSliderprintscrolleventdetails.htm and here is the code I'm running.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    final Slider slider = new Slider(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    slider.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 32);
    slider.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            String string = "SWT.NONE";
            switch (event.detail) {
                case SWT.DRAG:
                    string = "SWT.DRAG";
                    break;
                case SWT.HOME:
                    string = "SWT.HOME";
                    break;
                case SWT.END:
                    string = "SWT.END";
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_DOWN:
                    string = "SWT.ARROW_DOWN";
                    break;
                case SWT.ARROW_UP:
                    string = "SWT.ARROW_UP";
                    break;
                case SWT.PAGE_DOWN:
                    string = "SWT.PAGE_DOWN";
                    break;
                case SWT.PAGE_UP:
                    string = "SWT.PAGE_UP";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(slider.getSelection());
            System.out.println("Scroll detail -> " + string);
        }
    });
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: The source code for the Linux/GTK version of Slider appears to set the detail field.

Comment: After throwing break points in Slider class at all places where the detail are updated it appears that gtk_button_press_event always returns 0 aka NONE. This causes the gtk_change_value to always set the event detail to none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=51995) and [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21464) are said resolved, but not working on my machine(Ubuntu 12.04 eclipse version is Kepler).

Thus raised a new [bug here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402732).

Refer my post [SWT Scrollbar events on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288175/swt-scrollbar-events-on-linux/17987935#17987935) here I said other work around to detect these events.

Also wait check in  Eclipse Luna(to be release on 25th June).